# How to display the welcome page after successful log in?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am using following code in two different folder like Model and View. In View Folder contain two php file like Login.php and Login_success.php. Controller folder contain the mysql database table field fetch code. When I run below code It can't display the Login_success page. Only the else field **Check Name and password** displayed. These all file combined to out of folder index.php .

Here my code :

**Login.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<link rel ='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href = 'View/Design.css'> 
<script>
function Validate(){
var x=document.forms["login"]["username"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
 var x=document.forms["login"]["password"].value;
 if (x==null || x=="")
  {
   alert("Password must be filled out");
   return false;
  }
 }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form name = 'login' method = 'post' action = 'Controller/Controll.php' >
 <fieldset>
 <legend>Login</legend>
 User Name :<input type = 'text' name = 'username'>
 Password  :<input type = 'password' name = 'password'><br><br>
 <input type = 'submit' name = 'submit' value = 'submit' onsubmit = "return Validate()" >
 </fieldset>
 </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

**Controll.php**

```
 class Access{
 function connection(){
  require_once('View/Login.php');
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
 $db = mysql_select_db('Times_sheet');
 $query = mysql_query('select * from Login');
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
  if(($row['UserName']==$_POST['username']) && ($row['Password']==$_POST['password'])){
  require_once("View/Login_Success.php");
 }
  }
  else{
  echo "Check User name and Password";
 }
 }
 }
```

**Index.php**

```
require_once('Controller/Controll.php');
class login extends Access{
function getValu(){
require_once('View/Login.php');
}
 }
$Obj = new login();
$Obj ->getValu();
$Obj ->connection();
```

When I enter the correct user name and password it shoes the empty page. I don't know what mistake I did.

Comment: I can easily hack you system, simply if I disable JavaScript in my browser... Do not RELY ON CLIENT-SIDE validation !!

Answer (score 0):

you are just including `Login_success.php` in this line not redirecting to `Login_success.php`

```
 if(($row['UserName']==$_POST['username']) && ($row['Password']==$_POST['password'])){
    require_once("View/Login_Success.php");
 }
```

so use `header` for this redirection

```
 if(($row['UserName']==$_POST['username']) && ($row['Password']==$_POST['password'])){
    header("Location: View/Login_Success.php");
    exit();
 }
```

Comment: But the server does not check the condition if(($row['UserName']==$_POST['username']) && ($row['Password']==$_POST['password'])). It directly goes to the else part.

Answer (score 0):

In your query you are fetching all(*) result from the table 'Login'.

Instead of this query table with a 'WHERE' :
eg. select * from Login WHERE user= $_POST['username'] AND password = $_POST['password']

If the result found then redirect the user to your required page :

```
    header("Location : View/Login_Success.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

using header php function for redirect purpose instead of require_once. Like this format  header(url);

Answer (score 0):

You must change you code ,

```
 $query = mysql_query('select * from Login');
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

1. You SELECT all users from MySQL and after check on PHP it is not good way you can change it to : ( & MD5 your password because it is very important.)

> ```
> $user = $_POST['username'];
> $pass = MD5($_POST['password']);
> $query = mysql_query("select * from Login WHERE `UserName` = '$user' AND `Password` = '$pass' ");
> ```
>
> if (mysql_num_rows($query)==1)
>   {
>     // logined
>   }

and for save username and user in all page use session values :

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['UserName'] ;
```

and for use it in `Login_Success.php` you can use it this code :

```
<?php 

session_start();

echo "wellcome user : ".$_SESSION['user'] ;

?>
```

I have 2 offer for you:
1. use Anti SQL Injection in your code.
2. use header `header('location: View/Login_Success.php');` for redirect to other page not include

Comment: When I am tried based your guide lines finally I get the Error Like "Undefined index: username, Undefined index: password, mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: I'm edit answer to your code info , and fix answer test it now.

Comment: Yes I check when I am enter the user name and password it shows the empty page. If (mysql_num_rows($query)==1) { // logined } condition block can't execute. Still same problem.

Comment: I think your php is not very good please see this page for tutorial how made login page http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

Answer (score 0):

First, you code is not save at all; Peace a cake for hacking

```
 class Access{
 function connection(){
 require_once('View/Login.php');
 $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','root');
 $db = mysql_select_db('Times_sheet');
 $query = mysql_query('select * from Login');
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
```

Second, you are only including

```
 View/Login_Success.php'
```

You have to do it this way:

```
 if(($row['UserName']==$_POST['username']) && ($row['Password']==$_POST['password'])){
 header('location: View/Login_Success.php');
 }
 }
 else{
  echo "Check User name and Password";
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Yes I check it but the Login_success.php page does not open because the code if(isset($_POST['submit'])) is not run. It directly execute the else part.